# Enterprise Library 6 - VS 2015 - Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, enterprise-library-6

Will EL6 be supported on Win10 & VS 2015 in the near future?
I wanted to install the ConfigConsole.visx in order to configure all things in the designer.

> VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not
> installable on any currently installed products
>
> 13.09.2016 10:11:49 -     Supported Products :
> 13.09.2016 10:11:49 -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
> 13.09.2016 10:11:49 -             Version : [11.0]
> 13.09.2016 10:11:49 -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
> 13.09.2016 10:11:49 -             Version : [11.0]
> 13.09.2016 10:11:49 -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
> 13.09.2016 10:11:49 -             Version : [11.0]

[image]

Comment: VSIX is a zip, so unzip it, edit the manifest and add 14.0 as supported version, zip the folder again and rename the zip extension to VSIX and try to install it. Sometimes it works to get extensions working

Comment: Yeees, it works. Post it as an answer please and mention, that when you zip it back to zip only the contents of the vsix file and not the unpacked root folder. At least the installation worked. If it will run without problems, time will tell :-)

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VSIX extension is a zip file, so unzip it, edit the manifest and add 14.0 as supported version.

```
<InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[12.0,14.0]" />
<InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[12.0,14.0]" />
```

zip the content of the extracted folder again and rename the extension of the generated zip to VSIX and try to install the VSIX.